# how to modify the route in codeigniter to get correct data?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

i tried to do that

```
 $route['([a-z]{2})/pages/index/(:num)'] = "pages/(:num)";
```

this gave me error from db

```
 A PHP Error was encountered

 Severity: Warning

 Message: Missing argument 1 for Pages::index()

 Filename: controllers/pages.php

 Line Number: 14
```

because in my code i try to get the values from url and now  that function in controller trying to get the 5th part of url but can't find any parameter that depends on selection from db later , how to fix that ?

Comment: Im assuming you've got this line `$route['([a-z]{2})/pages/index/(:num)'] = "pages/(:num)";` in the config.php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$route['([a-z]{2})/pages/index/(:num)'] = "pages/(:num)";
```

try,

```
$route['([a-z]{2})/pages/index/(:num)'] = "pages/$1";
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html